# Filter PySpark column containing Null using not contains

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

When filtering a column:

Ex.

| Column |
| --- |
| DontShow |
| null |
| null |

using `df.filter(~col('Column).contains('DontShow))`

Expected result.

| Column |
| --- |
| null |
| null |

However, this returns nothing. I assume it treats null values differently. Seeing how this works in where I specify it could also be null: `df.filter(~(col('Column).contains('DontShow)) | col('Column').isNull())`

Out of curiosity why is this? One would assume it would return every row not containing the condition regardless if its null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isNull`

```
df.where(col('Column').isNull()).show()
```